# Booklist recommendation for Analysis Route.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am currently an undergraduate and I am particularly interested in mathematical analysis and pde and I hope to do some simple undergraduate research in mathematical analysis and pde in two years later.Here is the booklist I searched online and I have compiled all of them. Do I still lack of anything that required me to start to do research in mathematical analysis and pde? Do I need to add-on stochastic analysis in this booklist?

1)  Larry Smith Linear Algebra

2)  Apostol Calculus Volume 1 & 2

3)  Differential Equation with Boundary-Value Problem

4)  Elias M.Stein Fourier Analysis

5)  Rudin Principle of Mathematical Analysis

6)  Evans Partial Differential Equation

7)  Munkres Topology

8)  Rudin Complex and Real Analysis

9)  A First Course in Abstract Algebra Fraleigh

10) Rudin Functional Analysis

11) Elias M.Stein Harmonic Analysis

12) Hormander " An introduction to Complex Analysis in Several Variables"

13) doCarmo, Differential Geometry of Curve and Surfaces

14) Hirsch, Differential topology

I would appreciate it if you can give me any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Just start reading... Itll take years to go through this whole list. When you're 1/2,3/4 of the way you'll be able to judge for yourself which other books you need.

Comment: so is this list a solid list to go with ? Actually I have studied the first four in the list. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Just read the math you like. If you notice that you're getting stuck because you don't know enough about a topic, then go to the library to pick up a book to fill in some gaps in your knowledge.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

As you are interested in pde,  I would add [Brezis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=brezis+book+sobolev+spaces&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLrLaM7ZHUAhUBTJAKHezBDT8Q6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=brezis%20book%20sobolev%20spaces&f=false) (give special attention to chapters 8 and 9, which complement chapters 5 and 6 of Evans).